# Probability and Expected Value on picks

Tags: probability, expected-value

There are 3 empty boxes (A,B,C) where each box filled with 100 numbered balls (number 00 to number 99) each box. Every play cost me 1 coin and allow to select 1 number from 00 to 99, then a ball is drawn from each box.

There are prizes to be won as below:

Pool Prize : All 3 boxes draws same with your selection, Initial Pool is 100 coins and it will increase by 1 coin if the pool not hit.

Prize A : Box A draws the same number to your selection, 30 coins.

Prize B : Box B draws the same number to your selection, 20 coins.

Prize C : Box C draws the same number to your selection, 10 coins.

**My question:**

1. How do I calculate my chances on hitting the pool and proof that my expected value will become favor to me (from lost to earn)?
2. To proof my losses of coins control at -8% (negative 8 percent) when I hit the pool? 
   Example: I hit the pool on the 1,000th play, 1,000 coins on play but sum on my return is 920 coins, i lost 80 coins (8% of coins from 1,000 coins)

Logical assumption and changes allowed for no.2.

**What I understand:**

Each number has a probability of 1% where 1/100 = 0.01 (1%)

Hitting Box 1, 2, 3 = 30, 20, 10 Coins (each has 1% chance)

Return rate = 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 on every of my play and lost 0.4 each play.

Total Combination available is 
100 x 100 x 100 = 1,000,000

1 chance out of 1 million combination hitting the pool, where
0.01 x 0.01 x 0.01 = 0.000001 (0.0001%)

Comment: This is unfortunately quite hard to understand because it's largely ungrammatical. (For instance, "If the boxes appeared same numbers" makes no sense.) I'd suggest that you either post this in your native language and we try to find someone here who can translate it, or work with someone with a better command of English with whom you can go over the formulation.

Comment: Hi, please review again on the question if this is clear to understand? thanks

Comment: It's slightly improved, but still quite hard to follow. In English, boxes don't draw balls; the usual construction is the passive one: "A ball is drawn from each box." I still don't understand "To proof my losses of coins control at $-8\%$ when I hit the pool? " at all.

Comment: Hi, i have edited on the unclear information, please take a look. thanks

Comment: You've replaced only one occurrence of the ungrammatical active construction "the box draws"; the rest is unchanged (e.g. "Box $A$ draws the same number..."). More importantly, "To proof my losses of coins control at $-8\%$ (negative $8$ percent) when I hit the pool?" isn't any clearer than before. I'm not going to continue contributing to this inefficient process. I repeat my initial suggestion to either post the question in your native language and get it translated or work with someone with a better command of English who can go over it with you.

Comment: Please note that the accuracy of machine translations has improved considerably in recent years. A typical machine translation is considerably more grammatical and clear than this post. If you post in your native language, even if it turns out that no one here speaks it, a machine translation is still likely to improve your chances of making yourself understood.